# C# implement interface with missing assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface, .net-assembly

I have three assemblies. A main executable, a common library and an extension. In the extension, I need to implement a certain interface coming from the common assembly in order to register the class as a service in a static `Kernel` class.

The only problem, I don't have access to some types needed to implement the interface. For instance, the interface `A` has a method `DoWork()` that has a return type `B`. The extension assembly doesn't have the `B` type in its references and it cannot be added.

Is there a way to implement the interface, make the method throw a `NotImplementedException` and have the extension assembly compile?

Note, the main assembly needs to reference the extension in order to register it, so I can't reference the main assembly in the extension and declare the type in the main one.

Comment: probably not. sounds like type `B` should be present in the common library if you want the interface to be accessible to other assemblies.

Comment: The only thing is that I can't do this because the type `B` is in an external library :(

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do such a thing. You have to implement all members of the interface, and to do that you need references to all return types and parameter types of these members.

> Note, the main assembly needs to reference the extension in order to
>   register it, so I can't reference the main assembly in the extension
>   and declare the type in the main one.

How about adding a reference to the external library in your extension assembly? I think this is the only possibility you have here. I assume the extension will be deployed with the main assembly. Since the main assembly cannot function properly without the external library, you'll have all you need.